# Joining too tables on separate IDs from another table

Tags: sql

I have a database that consists of authors names first name, last names and book titles with sale prices.

I trying to create a query that will pull authors last names and first names that have books that have prices that are under $15.60 and display only there last name and first name in that order without any duplicate last name records.

columns - au_lname, au_fname, price
Tables - authers, titles

This is what I have so far...

```
SELECT DISTINCT au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors, titles, titleauthor
JOIN authors ON titleauthor.au_id = authors.au_id
 JOIN titles ON titleauthor.title_id = titles.title_id
WHERE price < 15.60
ORDER BY au_lname DESC
```

the table "titleauthor" has a key called "au_id" (which is also in the "authors" table) and a key called "title_id" (which is also in the "titles" table)
is this where I would JOIN them from? if so how do I go about doing that?

Here is the SQL file for the database
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Nzkg6T8VbgDL-xC282uNZ5coUD5bdFy-

[![Query Result][1]][1][image: Tables]

Comment: No duplicate last name? What do you want to do, if there are two different authors who share the same last name? Display only one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

I had the Syntax incorrect for the JOIN's

```
SELECT DISTINCT au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
JOIN titleauthor ON titleauthor.au_id = authors.au_id
 JOIN titles ON titleauthor.title_id = titles.title_id
WHERE price < 15.60
ORDER BY au_lname DESC
```

.
.
.
.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a `JOIN` condition between your tables.  It is not clear what that should be.

Second, you just need to remove `price` from the `SELECT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors a JOIN
     titles t
     ON a.? = t.?   -- surely there is a `JOIN` condition
WHERE t.price < 15.60
ORDER BY au_lname DESC
```